# Relation between height of an ideal and unimodular row

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra, noetherian, krull-dimension

A row $[b_1,\dots,b_{d+1}]$ is *unimodular* if there is $[a_1,\dots,a_{d+1}]$ such that
$a_1b_1+\cdots+a_{d+1}b_{d+1}=1$.

> Let $A$ be a Noetherian ring of dimension $d$ and $I$ be an ideal generated by $(b_1,\dots ,b_{d+1})$ elements. Now if $\mathrm{height}(I)>d$, then how do we get that the row $[b_1,\dots,b_{d+1}]$  is unimodular?

I have been told that this is a trivial thing but I am not able to understand how. Can someone explain how this is the case?

Comment: Possible hint: unpack the definition of the height of an ideal as well as the definition of the dimension of a ring. What does this say about an ideal $I$ of height greater than $d$? (Forget for a moment about a specific generating system for $I$.)

Comment: So do we get that $height(I) \leq dim(A)$?

Comment: Well, the height of $I$ is the infimum of the set $S(I)$ of heights of the prime ideals that contain $I$. If there is a prime ideal that contains $I$, then the inequality $\operatorname{height(I)}\le \dim(A)$ is true. But, the set $S(I)$ could be empty (what's an example where this happens?). The infimum of the empty set is conventionally taken to be $\infty$, and the source you're using ought to mention its convention regarding this possibility.

Comment: So when I consider $I=R$, then $height(I)=\infty$. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As we discussed in the comments, the condition $\operatorname{height}(I)>\dim A$ implies $I=A$, as the height of $I$ is the infimum of the heights of all prime ideals in $A$ containing $I$. Thus, we have
$$1\in I = (b_1,\dots,b_{d+1})$$
and this means there exist $a_1,\dots,a_{d+1}\in A$ such that
$$1 = a_1b_1+\dots+a_{d+1}b_{d+1}$$